# Issue getting Datetime value from a query. Value always the same

Tags: symfony, doctrine

From a query, i am trying to get dates in symfony 2.0. My query is working well but the date is always the same. How can i get the correct date from the database. Here is some code

```
    $query = $em -> createQuery('SELECT x FROM TableUserBundle:User x WHERE x.id = :id')
                     -> setParameter('id', $event -> getUserAdminId());
        $results = $query -> getResult();


    foreach($results as $eventInfos) {
        var_dump($eventInfos[0] -> getUpdated());
    }
```

This always return me the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Why do expect a user update date to change without actually updating the user?

Comment: The updated field won't change itself by just querying it - you will need to update the User Object itself.
Then use some logic written by your own or LiveCycleCallbacks to get the field updated

Answer (score 0):

1) Why do you need `foreach` if there's no JOIN (thus no multiple dates) in you query?

2) Method `getResult()`, by default, hydrates `object` so you don't have`[0]` index within **loop item**. Rather you would do:

```
var_dump($results[0]->getUpdated());
```

And since you're acquiring `User` by primary key you might also want to use built-in `find` method, since it's way simpler:

```
$user = $em->find($event -> getUserAdminId()); // returns only single record
var_dump($user->getUpdated())
```

Comment: Oh actually! I've just pasted some parts of the code sorry if I made it blurry but I am actually getting the $results as an array.